# Handling deep links in compose SingleActivity app without multiple app instances and ugly animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, deep-linking, android-deep-link, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have the `SingleActivity` app developed with `Jetpack Compose` and `compose navigation`.

I need to handle deep links with query parameters.

At the moment my implementation includes the definition of deep links in the `NavHost` and this is all.

But I have few issues with this approach:

- ugly animation with blinking after the splash screen when I try to navigate to the app by clicking on the deep link
- if app has already opened and I click on the link - I have 2 instances of the app in the recents

How can I solve these issues?

Comment: "if app has already opened and I click on the link - I have 2 instances of the app in the recents" -- you can attempt to manage that via `android:launchMode` and related manifest attributes. Note that this is unrelated to Jetpack Compose. "ugly animation with blinking after the splash screen when I try to navigate to the app by clicking on the deep link" -- you might want to record a screencast of what you are seeing and provide that along with a [mcve] of your implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by changing `launchMode` of the `MainActivity` to `singleTask`. Previously it was a default `standard` mode:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

And adding handling deep link by `NavHostController` in the `setContent` function inside the `onCreate` method of `MainActivity`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {
    private val viewModel: AppViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        actionBar?.hide()
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {
            val appState = rememberMyAppState()

            // add this
            DisposableEffect(Unit) {
                val listener = Consumer<Intent> {
                    appState.value.navController.handleDeepLink(it)
                }
                addOnNewIntentListener(listener)
                onDispose { removeOnNewIntentListener(listener) }
            }
         ...
         }
}
```

Also to fix blinking between splash and other app content I changed `containerColor` and `contentColor` of my main `Scaffold`